# How to break single row into multiple rows in dataframe base on column values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe(like below), I need to break each row to several rows based on conditions in value columns for future pivot analysis.  (condition: if column is blank then skip)

original dataframe:

```
  ID     name     apple pear banana
  01     xyz       10          3
  02     abc       9     10    5 
  03     def       8           9
  04     fds       5
```

desired dataframe:

```
  ID  Attribute1  Name  value
  01     xyz      apple   10
  01     xyz      banana   3
  02     abc      apple    9
  02     abc      pear    10
  02     abc      banana   5
  03     def      apple    8
  03     def      banana   9
  04     fds      apple    5
```

I am new to pandas data analytics. (used a lot VBA as an old fashioned guy)I am trying to use `iteritems()` and `.loc` but did not success. please help!

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
for row in df.iterrows():
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `melt`

```
df.melt(id_vars = ['ID', 'name']).dropna().sort_values('ID')
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty straightforward: replace the empty strings with NaNs, convert the first two columns to a multiindex, convert the remaining columns to yet another index level. The missing values are discarded at this point.

```
result = df.replace('', np.nan)\
           .set_index(['ID','name']).stack().reset_index()
#   ID name level_2   0
#0  01  xyz   apple  10
#1  01  xyz  banana   3
#2  02  abc   apple   9
#3  02  abc    pear  10
#4  02  abc  banana   5
#5  03  def   apple   8
#6  03  def  banana   9
#7  04  fds   apple   5
```

Optionally, rename the columns:

```
result.rename({'level_2': 'Attribute1', 0: 'value'}, axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you prof. DYZ for the quick response. somehow, there's traceback saying 'np' is not defined. most like my fault. This helps me a lot in understanding .melt and .stack methods. thanks!

Comment: You should `import numpy as np`, it is a standard convention